# How to use array variable into mysql query in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array variable like this

```
$variable[] = $data['master_software_capability_id'];
```

How to use this array variable in SQL query

Is this the right way ?

```
SELECT * FROM software_capability where software_capability_id IN ($variable);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implode the array to comma separated string

```
$variables_imploded = implode(",",$variable);

"SELECT * 
FROM software_capability 
where software_capability_id IN 
(".$variables_imploded.")";
```

Comment: @Senthilkumar please accept this answer as accepted so it will be marked as solved

Answer (score 1):

use JOIN or IMPLODE

```
$variables_joins = join(',',$variable);  

SELECT * FROM software_capability where software_capability_id IN ($variables_joins);
```